# Vue js - How to iterate an array inside an array?

Tags: vue.js

I need some dynamic select boxes when given a certain count.
For that I have used two arrays -

```
(i)Array of index (count)
(ii)Array of values.
```

For first one I have used a v-model (as it need some dynamic input boxes) and second I have just used key and took out its value.

I have tried doing it with single iteration using second array but it failed regression testing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 3,
    call: [1, 2, 3],
    sms: [4, 5, 6]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label is-small">Total Count</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input type="text" v-model="count">
      <div class="field" v-for="k in Number(count)">
        <select class="input" v-model="call[k]">
          <option value="" selected>Select Call Hours</option>
          <option v-for="hour in 24">{{hour}}</option>
        </select>
        <select class="input" v-model="sms[k]">
          <option value="" selected>Select SMS Hours</option>
          <option v-for="hour in 24">{{hour}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a part of a form, it works correctly while newly adding data but while editing the values do not appear properly. The first index of call and sms array is left out each time.

Comment: Can you setup a codesandbox example with your data structure?

Comment: Vue's [`v-for` with a Range](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) iterates from `[1, Range]`. Try `call[k - 1]` and `sms[k - 1]`

Comment: Why dont you just use the index for keeping place. Like this:
`v-for="(hour, index) in 24"` then you have the element and index in one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that array starts from 0. So, one way is to subtract *k - 1*. Example:

`sms[k - 1]`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 3,
    call: [1, 2, 3],
    sms: [4, 5, 6]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label is-small">Total Count</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input type="text" v-model="count">
      <div class="field" v-for="k in Number(count)">
        <select class="input" v-model="call[k - 1]">
          <option value="" selected>Select Call Hours</option>
          <option v-for="hour in 24">{{hour}}</option>
        </select>
        <select class="input" v-model="sms[k - 1]">
          <option value="" selected>Select SMS Hours</option>
          <option v-for="hour in 24">{{hour}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```